# Maximizing compatibility for bootable USB flash drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive, livecd, liveusb

I wish to have a set of bootable USB sticks in my EDC/travel kit. I have a small case in which I can carry a few tiny USB sticks. What configurations should I opt for in order to maximise compatibility for the variety of computers (new and old) I might come across?

Right now I have a stick with `Puppu Linux 32bit`, and setting it up with `Rufus`, I opted for the `MBR` and `BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)` settings.

My need is just to have these as a backup, for emergency use, if my phone or laptop are unavailable.

Edit: The stick has been formatted as `FAT32`.

Comment: All modern and supported processors by Intel only support UEFI boot.  If you need to support Legacy boot is entirely dependent on the age of the equipment you will be using. In a few years there probably won’t be equipment that doesn’t at least support UEFI boot mode.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Since I want to be prepared, I don't want to assume anything about the hardware I might encounter. My aim is to be able to access my own "secure system" on any PC I might come across. Personal use only, let's say my laptop and phone has been stolen and I want to access my email or bank account.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you should have the stick set to MBR mode: just know that you may run into times where you have to turn on compatibity mode in order for the EFI to recognize it, espically on systems where SecureBoot has been enabled. Also, make sure that the stick is formatted in FAT32 (should be the default for Rufus).

Apart from that, I would also suggest:

- A stick each for the install media of [Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) and Servers [2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2), [2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016), and [2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2019)
- If Puppy Linux doesn't have chntpw, I'd recommend an extra stick with something like [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images/) to allow you to get into personal PCs where users have forgotten their passwords.

Comment: You are right about Secure Boot and that I might need to disable it. And yes, forgot to mention that it is formatted as FAT32. However, is there any system that this stick wouldn't boot on?

Comment: If those system have Secure Boot enable and have implemented BitLocker protection be prepare to provide the BitLocker Recovery key.

Comment: Why would it be a good idea to carry all these install-media sticks?

Comment: Ramhound is right about BitLocker: there are some cases where you will be able to reenable SecureBoot and it will be fine, but to be safe, make sure you temporarily disable BL before you disable SecureBoot. 

In any case, the only way that stick wouldn't boot is for SecureBoot, but you can just have an identical stick with a different boot record, no problem.
Regarding the install media, I'd say those are going to be the most common systems you're going to run into as a technician; it's good to be prepared.